# Select Specific Elements from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML structure

```
<books>
   <crime>
      <crime_book title="abc" />
      <crime_book title="def" />
   </crime>
   <vacation>
      <vacation_book title="ghi" />
   </vacation>
   <drama />
</books>
```

How can I get all books in one list?

I have

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("filename");
var query = from element in doc.Root.Elements()
            select element;
```

but that gives me only the book types. I want to skip that level.

Comment: [`doc.Descendents("book")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx)?

Comment: @Blorgbeard You're right, read too quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enumerable.SelectMany`:

```
doc.Root.Elements().SelectMany(n => n.Elements());
```

Basically the same as `Select`, but it flattens the sequence one level.

Answer (score 4):

Simple,

```
var query = doc.Descendants("book");
```

**EDIT**

To get the book in all levels

```
var query = xDoc.Descendants()
            .Where(d => d.Name.LocalName.EndsWith("_book"));
```

or

```
var query = xDoc.Descendants()
            .Where(d => d.Parent != null)
            .Where(d => d.Name.LocalName == d.Parent.Name.LocalName + "_book");
```

Comment: 1+ yes Descendants will do the job

Comment: @I4V: You are right. Thats how to do it. The problem is - I did not describe my problem correctly. My structure is a little different. See my update. Sorry.

Comment: @juergend but you changed the question completely

Comment: I missed the detail that the elements are named differently in that level.

Answer (score 1):

How about using XPath? assuming only books have an attribute `title`

```
var query = doc.XPathSelectElements("//*[@title]");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want a list of titles, so this would put them in an `IEnumerable<XAttribute>`:

```
var titleAttributes = doc.Descendants().SelectMany(e => e.Attributes("title"));
```

Works no matter how nested elements with a `title` attribute are and regardless of element names being different at various levels as per your comments on the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another one liner option is to check for the title attribute

```
var result = doc.Descendants().Where(x=>x.Attribute("title") != null);
```